# Raspberry pi mesh network ROS2 setup

Tags: networking

I am working on a project where im going to be running multiple raspberry pis with ROS2 on a wifi network. To extend range im planning on running a mesh network. Im planning on creating the mesh network using batman-adv. I have tested this and works between 2 raspberrys. However my question is.

If i have the next situation

Robot1 ->> Robot2 ->> Robot3 ->> Robot4

Above is a simplified mesh network, where robot1 is connect to robot2, 2 is connected to 1 and 3 etc. My question is, If i run a ROS2 node + topic on Robot1, am i able to see this ROS2 topic on Robot4? Does this depend on my mesh network setup? To simplify, can i ping robot 4 from robot 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Please don't cross post! 2. This is a batman-adv question so you should change the topic. 3. Is this a Raspberry Pi question ? I think your question is more suited in a ROS2 forum.

Comment: Thanks! I think i can break down my question more. So I am going to try!.